# How to save file to shared drive on network with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, networking, shared-directory

Using trying to write code that will save a file to a shared drive on our network.  If I use a mapped drive as the destination location (i.e. R:...) then it works with no problem.  BUT, not everyone is mapped to that, so I want to be able to save the file use \ourserver\serverfolder ...

when I try to replace "R:\" & filename with "\ourserver\serverfolder\" & file name, I get an error 76, "File Path Not Found."

In essence, the question is how do I save a file to a shared drive, using the shared drive path, via vba?

the sample code takes sourcefile "C:\houses\myhouse.pdf" ... and wants to save to destination file "\ourserver\serverfolder\anotherfolder\myhouse.pdf"

```
Private Sub CopyRenameFile(ByRef SourceFile As String, ByRef DestinationFile As String)
On Error Resume Next
    FileCopy SourceFile, DestinationFile
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "CopyRenameFile() Class FileMoverMove", , True)
            MsgBox "Copy error: " & SourceFile
        End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

You are close as you just miss one leading backslash in the UNC path:

```
DestinationFile = "\\ourserver\serverfolder\" & file name
```